# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm to trigger a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi there I'm creating an alarm which I want to post to an SNS topic which triggers a lambda. I do not want the alarm to email anyone.  However, i am repeatedly getting errors such as the following:

(Warning: this alarm is not configured to notify. Please modify this alarm and add an email address.)

Do I have to specify an email address?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add your SNS Topic to the AlarmActions of the alarm.  Be aware that the lambda, once configured properly, will only fire when the alarm changes state.

Comment: Whats your Lambda code, you need to return success from the receiving Lambda or it'll think it's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the way that the Alarm was created on the Scaling Policy.

When an Amazon SNS topic already exists and an Alarm is created on a Scaling Policy, the UI looks like this:

[image]

This allows an existing SNS topic to be selected.

However, when there is no SNS topic and the user clicks **create topic**, the UI looks like this:

[image]

It is possible that the interface is using the 2nd configuration and the "with these recipients" field is empty.

If so, you can cancel that selection and choose the SNS topic from the drop-down list.